# Visual Studio Xamarin Android - invalid resource directory name

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

Annoying bug. I clean the project and re-compile it again - still this error occurs, what could be the problem?

**Picture 1**
[image: Picture 1]
**Picture 2**

[image]

**Picture 3**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change from AndroidResource to Compile, clean the project and try again.